# How can you prevent someone destroying your app if they get into your account on heroku?

Tags: heroku

Heroku is wonderful but it's slightly concerning that if your Heroku login is compromised someone can simply destroy your entire app and business.

Is there any way of preventing this using multi factor authentication or similar?

Comment: Voting to close as not-constructive. It's not like you can alter Heroku's security mechanism, so the only answer to this question is, AFAIK, "you can't." [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) would be a better place for the general discussion going on here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would treat this scenario the same as a fire, flood, or hardware failure. What you're describing is essentially a [disaster recovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disaster_recovery) scenario. Make regular app and DB backups (your code really should be in a distributed, secure source control solution, such as git), and follow best-practices for password security in the first place.

If you're looking for a 100% guaranteed solution, it doesn't exist. The best you can do is have good password security and backup practices, which will lower your risk of compromise/failure to the point that a Heroku failure becomes mathematically more likely than an unrecoverable compromise such as you outline.

When it comes to disaster recovery, you have to have a backup plan.

Comment: I wouldn't say it was going that far. I'm just concerned that in order to delete an app on heroku all you need to do is login and press delete. If an entire business revolves around the application then surely at least two-factor authentication is to be expected no?

Comment: Well, maybe that's crossing how easy it is to login, with how easy it is to get your password - they're definitely not the same. I agree that two-factor authentication would be very nice. I suppose my point is, password-based authentication is still extremely strong - it just puts the burden of secrecy on the user, whereas two-factor authentication can allow your password to get free, but you would still have the safety net of the second factor. There's no reason that, if you're able to keep your password absolutely private, that it isn't every bit as good.

Comment: If you're working on a team where multiple people need to have access, does heroku provide key-based authentication, whereby users would each have their own access key which you can revoke?

Comment: I do take your point and as I was thinking about it I realised that it's no different for most other hosting providers - Lindode only needs a username/password. However it does seem incredibly vulnerable in that even with your disaster recovery plans you could still face a huge knock to business. No user-based authentication though unfortunately

Comment: All the more reason to take password security *very* seriously. It's great that you're thinking of all the possible ways someone could get in. The other (arguably more likely), scenario is that someone breaks in using social engineering. I.E. if your password security is sufficiently good, then the likelihood that someone will get in with a compromised/brute-force password attack is effectively zero, but that doesn't protect you from employees inadvertently providing information that results in compromised security. After you solve your password problem, move toward educating your employees.

Comment: Recent, very serious social engineering example: http://krebsonsecurity.com/tag/fortune-100/

Comment: You know, after thinking it over for a couple of days, I'm going to take back what I said earlier. I've come to agree with you much more in general. Because of possible problems such as password database theft (even if unlikely) I do support two-factor authentication in all mission-critical software. So, in the case of Heroku, two-factor authentication would protect your app from being destroyed if someone was able to steal, and decrypt the authentication database, because if someone was able to break in and steal your password, they would *still* need your second factor to do damage.

Comment: I'm glad that you do feel that way. It does seem crazy to me that an entire business could literally rest on a single password. However good ones processes are that password is always somewhat vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

The big picture here is **Business Continuity Plan**. Don't leave work without one. Questions like:

1. What is the backup solution for a compromised or failed website? Time to full recovery?
2. How do you respond to customer during this downtime? **(important)**
3. What is your alternate (eg: manual, paper) solution when the site is down?
4. On recovery, what are steps to take to ensure no data is lost?
5. How do you resume your business back to 'normal' operation?
6. What steps to take to maintain the customer confidence or relationship? **(important)**

It's like spending time on a fire drill, or money on a fire extinguisher. Seems like a waste but when "poop" hit the fan, it can save your life (the business in your case).

Answer (score -1):

one word answer to your original question;

No